# C++Builder correct way to Load string from ressources

Tags: c++, string, delphi, text, c++builder

I am new in either c++, and c++builder(11 v-28), i have put in ressources a text file(via projet->Ressources and Images), but i can't find any method to retrieve my text from ressources, LoadStr(..) function reclaim a numeric identifier that i can't found or how to get it.

Comment: Hi - please clarify have you put the strings into the resources for the program (Using Project | Tools and Resources) or have you put them in a text file which you have included into the program as a resource or have you just put them in a text file?

Comment: @Rob Lambden, yes i have put my long text file in ressources via projet->Ressources and Images,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using C++ Builder you can use functions in the RTL to help you.

When you put the large text file into the resources you would have given it a type and Id.  Normally for an embedded file the type would by RT_RCDATA.

(I haven't checked this code at all so it probably won't compile, but should give you a pointer)

```cpp
  TStream * function TMyForm::GetResourceStream(UnicodeString szResName);
  {
  TStream:     rc;
  id:          int;

    rc=nil;
    id=StrToIntDef(szResName, 0);
    if(id > 0)
    {
      rc = TResourceStream::CreateFromID(hInstance, id, RT_RCDATA);
    }
    return(rc);
  }
```

Th hInstance is the Instance of your program that is passed to WinMain.

Once you have the `TStream` you can read from it.  You could populate a TStringList for example.

Comment: Why not directly   TStream* strm= new TResourceStream(
     (int)HInstance, "MY_RESS_NAME", RT_RCDATA);?

Comment: You can instantiate from a resource name.  From habit (and because of recommendations to use Ids rather than names) I have used CreateFromID.  As CreateFRomID is an overloaded constructor you should be able to use new TResourceStream( hInstance, id, RT_RCDATA);

If your method works then of course by all means go ahead and use that.